# What is the reason for delay to query data in Bigquery when partitioned at ingestion time?

Tags: google-bigquery

I was using `bigquery` to batch `insert` data from my `python` application. The tables were `partitioned` at ingestion time. The difference I saw was data that I inserted would appear for a `query` after 1.5 hrs after ingestion.

Later I changed the `schema` to have a `timestamp` column

This time I could `query` data immediately after ingestion.

Why is there a difference in behavior between `_PARTITIONTIME` pseudo-column vs `timestamp` column in the table `schema`?

**PYTHON CODE FOR INGESTION:**

This is a simplified version of the code:

```py
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
TABLE_REF = bigquery_client.dataset('DATASET_ID').table('TABLE_ID')
TABLE = bigquery_client.get_table(TABLE_REF)

def ingest_to_bq(data: LIST[LIST]):
    bigquery_client.insert_rows(TABLE, data)
```

**Table Schema:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "epoch_ms",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "application_id",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "ack_id",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "data",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    }
]
```

Created the table from the BIGQUERY interface and partitioned at ingestion time.

**Query:**

I query again using BIGQUERY interface.

```
SELECT data from <DATASET_ID>.<TABLE_ID> WHERE _PARTITIONTIME="2020-03-30"
```

The above query would not display results that was ingested let say, half an hour back. It takes roughly 1.5 hours after ingestion to get the results.

**NEW SCHEMA:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "send_timestamp",
        "type": "TIMESTAMP",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "application_id",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "ack_id",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "data",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    }
]
```

**QUERY FOR NEW SCHEMA:**

```
SELECT data from <DATASET_ID>.<TABLE_ID> WHERE send_timestamp>="2020-03-30 00:00:00" and send_timestamp<="2020-03-30 23:59:59"
```

This query gives back the result immediately after ingestion. I don't have to wait.

Comment: Please add more details. For example, the relevant queries

Comment: Can you please provide more information. Your schema, the format of the timestamp you ar e using, and also the python code you are using to interact with BigQuery

Comment: May you explain what are you doing to create your table in both cases? I dont fully understand what is the difference between the two approaches.

Comment: Added more detail to the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The explanation for this delay is the `BigQuery`'s **streaming buffer**. The streaming buffer is a a buffer that retains recently inserted rows and is optimized for writing throughput. In other words, when you insert streaming data into `BigQuery` your data is firstly inserted into the streaming buffer where it stays up to 90 minutes. At this point, data is considered durable and you can query it however you are not allowed to do some specific operations over it.

As you can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#the_partitiontime_pseudo_column), when your data is in the **streaming buffer**, your `_PARTITIONTIME` pseudo column will be `NULL`. Given that, your query is not able to find the new inserted rows because your `_PARTITIONTIME` is `NULL`. To be sure that the values are `NULL` in your pseudo column for the recently inserted data, you can run the queries below.

1. If you want to see the pseudo column for all the rows, run `SELECT *, _PARTITIONTIME p from <DATASET_ID>.<TABLE_ID>`
2. If you want to get all the rows where the pseudo column is null, run `SELECT * from <DATASET_ID>.<TABLE_ID> WHERE _PARTITIONTIME is null`

Finally, I would like to add some usefull references for this topic.

1. BigQuery partitioned table's [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables).
2. BigQuery streaming [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability).
3. An official [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/life-of-a-bigquery-streaming-insert) about streaming into BigQuery which discuss the streaming buffer and how to handle it.

I hope it helps

Comment: Somehow i missed reading about streaming buffer. Thank You so much for answering.